# MySQL query optimisation with date ranges

Tags: mysql

Thank you for reading. I have a booking system which I am trying to search availability but the query is taking a huge amount of time to run. Does anyone have any pointers on how I can get this to run quicker?

The `dates` table is a list of every date from 2015 to 2030.
The `property_bands` table are date ranges of available dates for properties
The `booking_properties` table is a list of all bookings

When I run the below query without the `booking_properties` table, the query takes 0.17 seconds, but with the "left join" it takes 54 seconds.

```
SET @start = '2018-05-01' , @end = '2018-05-04';

select * from `dates`

left join `property_bands` on property_bands.propband_start <= dates.day_date
and property_bands.propband_end >= dates.day_date

left join `booking_properties` on booking_properties.property_id = property_bands.property_id
and(
    (
        booking_properties.bprop_start <= @start
        and booking_properties.bprop_end >= @end
    )
    or(
        booking_properties.bprop_start >= @start
        and booking_properties.bprop_start < @end
    )
    or(
        booking_properties.bprop_end > @start
        and booking_properties.bprop_end <= @end
    )
)
and(
    booking_properties.bprop_deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    or booking_properties.bprop_deleted > now()
)
and booking_properties.bprop_void < 1
where
    dates.day_date >= @start and dates.day_date < @end
```

I am attempting to rewrite a query that I wrote in 2009 which has always worked well but as the client's platform has grown, the system has got slower and slower. Here is the original query which takes 14 seconds to run currently.

```
SELECT datediff('2018-05-04', '2018-05-01') as `nights`,
    '2018-05-01' as arrival, 
    '2018-05-04' as departure, 
    sum(property_bands.propband_pricedirect) as bookingprice, 
    sum(property_bands.propband_pricespecial) as bookingspecial, 
    datediff('2018-05-04', '2018-05-01')-(count(*)) as mismatch, 
    property_bands.propband_minduration,
    properties.*,
    resorts.resort_name,
    resorts.resort_area,
    resorts.resort_country,
    resorts.resort_url,
    resorts.resort_tripid,
    resorts.resort_desc,
    property_types.proptype_name, (

    select booking_properties.booking_id from booking_properties where booking_properties.property_id = property_bands.property_id and ((booking_properties.bprop_start <= '2018-05-01' and booking_properties.bprop_end >= '2018-05-04') 
    or (booking_properties.bprop_start >= '2018-05-01' and booking_properties.bprop_start < '2018-05-04') or (booking_properties.bprop_end > '2018-05-01' and booking_properties.bprop_end <= '2018-05-04')) 
    and booking_properties.company_id = '100' and (booking_properties.bprop_deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or booking_properties.bprop_deleted > now()) and booking_properties.bprop_void < 1 limit 1) as booking_id

    FROM dates, property_bands, properties, property_types, resorts

    where properties.property_id = property_bands.property_id and property_types.proptype_id = properties.proptype_id
    and dates.day_date >= '2018-05-01' 
    and dates.day_date < '2018-05-04' 
    and property_bands.propband_start <= dates.day_date 
    and property_bands.propband_end >= dates.day_date

    and resorts.resort_id = properties.resort_id


    and (property_bands.propband_deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or property_bands.propband_deleted > now()) 
    and (properties.property_deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or properties.property_deleted > now())
    and (resorts.resort_deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or resorts.resort_deleted > now())
    group by property_bands.property_id order by properties.booking_count asc;
```

Comment: Have you tried moving those conditions from ON into the WHERE clause?

Comment: @buffjape But that might change the logic of the query.

Comment: i don't think so. Try it and see, or work it out...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). And, in addition to SHOW CREATE TABLES, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for same.

Comment: As an aside, the test for overlaps (if that's what this is) is far simpler than your query implies: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and end after Event B starts.

Comment: Thanks buffjape, I have tried as a sperate where clause and the query takes exactly the same amount of time.

Comment: You are correct Strawberry, the query is searching for any bookings that may overlap my query dates. There would then be a seperate where clause to ensure that this is null so that I do not show properties that overlap.